# Правильно ли построена данная фраза?

Tags: управление, число

"Женский и мужской мозг устроен по-разному".
Или "Между женским и мужским мозгом существуют различия".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первое предложение написано в разговорном стиле, но требует правки: "устроен" надо поставить во множественном числе - "устроены". Второе написано сухим строгим языком, подходит для научной статьи. Построено правильно.